# Overlapping of Keyword and Comparison Word

Tags: c++, algorithm, overlap

How can I code if statements that give me the following results:

Keyword = face

Comparison Words (user input) = effac, acer

Some examples to give an idea of what I mean:

```
 Keyword: face
 Match: effac
 Overlap: 3 (fac)

 Keyword: face
 Match: acer
 Overlap: 3 (ace)

 Keyword: llama
 Match: amazing
 Overlap: 3 (ama)

 Keyword: lame
 Match: lament
 Overlap: 4 (lame)
```

I think I need to use substr? Or just in general, what can I do to figure out how to determine the overlap of these two scenarios? I already have the functions ready, I just need to figure out what conditionals I need to put into my if/else statements, and the body of the if/else code block.

Comment: It seems what you are looking for is a sequence alignment algorithm. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment

Comment: That is not what I need. My overlap can only happen at the beginning or end of the words as shown. It cannot be in between the words compared. I just need to know what conditionals I need to use to find these specific cases of overlapping instances.. but I don't know how to do it. It's not as complicated as the sequence alignments.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string>

std::string longestCommonSubstr( std::string& s, std::string& in) {
    size_t s_s = s.size();
    size_t in_s = in.size();
    if ( ( s_s == 0) || ( in_s == 0)) return std::string();
    size_t common_s = std::min( s_s, in_s);
    for ( size_t i = common_s; i > 0; i--) {
        size_t pos_beg = 0;
        size_t pos_end = i;
        while ( pos_end < s_s + 1) {
            std::string searched =  s.substr( pos_beg, pos_end);
            size_t found = in.find( searched);
            if ( found != std::string::npos) return searched;
            ++pos_beg;
            ++pos_end;
        }
    }
    return std::string();
}
```

usage:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::string me( "face");
    std::string ymey( "effac");
    std::string res = longestCommonSubstr( me, ymey); // res is "fac"
    if ( !res.empty()) {
        // found
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sketchy pseudocode that I think should work, I am assuming a match can occur at the beginning OR(strictly) at the end.

```
//first case overlap is either in the beginning or the end for both words

count = 0
for i = 0 to word.length - 1
  if word[i] == match[i]
    count++
  else
    break;

if count != 0
  //output first count letters
else //you dont have your match in the beginning, check for the end
  for i = word.length - 1 to 0
    if word[i] == match[i]
      count++
    else
      break;

if count != 0
      //output last count letters

//second case overlap is at the opposite ends

for i = 0 to word.length - 1
  if word[i] == match[match.length - 1 - i]
    count++
  else
    break;

if count != 0
  //output first count letters
else //you dont have your match in the beginning, check for the end
  for i = 0 to word.length - 1 
    if word[word.length - 1 - i] == match[i]
      count++
    else
      break;

if count != 0
      //output last count letters
```

Comment: But wouldn't this be starting at the index 0? Which is not what I wanted to do because I already have conditionals for those types of cases. I am looking specifically for cases that doesn't start at index 0, and can start anywhere else AS LONG AS it ends in 

      word.at(word.size() - 1)

So like... some examples:

      Keyword: face
      Match: acer
      Overlap: 3 (due to ace)

OR

      Keyword: face
      Match: cent
      Overlap: 2 (due to ce)

It MUST end in the last letter of the keyword. So if the comparison word was atce, there would be no overlap.

Sorry!

Comment: @user3397245 I got you. I extended the pseudocode, to cover that case. It is the same logic, anyway. And note that this is still not complete as you need to check some cases where they have different length etc. but it should give you an idea.

Comment: Should I be incrementing the variable i? And can you explain this code:

  if word[i] == match[match.length - 1 - i]

Comment: I understand that it tests the letter at key.at(0) against the letter at match.at(match.size() - 1 - i), but why did you do - i? Doesn't that make it test against the match in the wrong direction?

Comment: @user3397245 increment is implied in pseudocode. and you are right it matches in the wrong direction. it gets more complicated, I am sorry for the confusion. I will keep the answer just to keep the discussion here. But it does not work. Using default substring functions seems inevitable.

Comment: @user3397245 have you noticed my solution?

Comment: Sigh. I've been working on this assignment for over 6 hours today alone. I feel ridiculously incapable of coding. Think I'll just give up. Got a 34% on it so far, it's obvious that I don't understand the concept. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Yes, lizusek, I have noticed your solution. But I did not learn coding in that way at all so I don't quite follow your code. I'm sorry!!

Comment: @user3397245 no worries. But this is simple, basic C++. You have tagged question with C++ that is why I have come with my solution. You can simply copy-paste and you will find that it works. You can ask in case of any problems.

Comment: Oh yes, I learned C++ but I'm a beginner and this is my first coding class EVER. I'm not even a CS major haha it was just an elective. I will test it out, thanks :)

Comment: @user3397245 we can go on [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49332/overlapping-of-keyword-and-comparison-word) if you want further assistance

Comment: May I show you my assignment and what I have so far? My coding is a bit sloppy though but you can ignore most of it and just go straight to my functions at the bottom, hold on! And thanks for your help!